# JSON to Gson - Value cannot be converted to JSONObject7

Tags: android, gson, activeandroid

I'm creating `Database` from `JSON`. I get this error when I run app: 
 Problem parsing the news `JSON` results
    `org.json.JSONException:` Value Trump of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`

**Here is code:**

```
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty( newsJSON )) {
        return null;
    }

    List<News> newsall = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        JSONArray results = data.getJSONArray("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
            String webTitle = obj.getString("title");
            String webUrl = obj.getString("url");
            String webImage = obj.getString( "urlToImage" );

            List<NewsForDB> newsForDB = new ArrayList<>(  );
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            NewsForDB webTitleForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webTitle ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
            newsForDB.add(webTitleForDB);
            NewsForDB urlForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webUrl ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
            newsForDB.add(urlForDB);
            NewsForDB webImageForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webImage ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
            newsForDB.add( webImageForDB );


            News news = new News(webTitle, webUrl, webImage);
            newsall.add(news);

        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
    }
    return newsall;
}
```

**When there are no this lines of code**

```
List<NewsForDB> newsForDB = new ArrayList<>(  );
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        NewsForDB webTitleForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webTitle ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
        newsForDB.add(webTitleForDB);
        NewsForDB urlForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webUrl ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
        newsForDB.add(urlForDB);
        NewsForDB webImageForDB=gson.fromJson( extractFeatureFromJson( webImage ).toString(), NewsForDB.class );
        newsForDB.add( webImageForDB );
```

Everything works great, but I'm trying to prepare code to use `ActiveAndroid ORM.`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I am following first answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118636/storing-json-data-to-local-database-in-android).

News:

```
public class News {
private String mWebTitle;
private String mUrl;
private String mImage;

public News(String webTitle, String webUrl, String webImage) {
    mWebTitle = webTitle;
    mUrl = webUrl;
    mImage = webImage;

}

public String getWebTitle() {
    return mWebTitle;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return mUrl;
}
public String getWebImage() {return mImage;}
```

}

And here is part of code from QueryUtils, which is before that posted in first question

```
public static List<News> fetchNewsData(String requestUrl) {
    URL url = createUrl( requestUrl );

    String jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest( url );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e );
    }

    List<News> news = extractFeatureFromJson( jsonResponse );

    return news;
}
```

And here is NewsForDB.java

```
    import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;


@Table(name = "NewsDB")

public class NewsForDB extends Model {

    @Column(name = "title", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "url")
    public String url;

    @Column(name = "urlToImage")
    public String urlToImage;

    public NewsForDB(){
        super();
    }

    public NewsForDB(String title, String url, String urlToImage){
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit code just like this !

```
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty( newsJSON )) {
        return null;
    }

    List<News> newsall = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        JSONArray results = data.getJSONArray("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
            News news = gson.fromJson(obj.toString() , News.class);
            newsall.add(news);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
    }
    return newsall;
}
```

Comment: Code works, thank You! Now I get empty ListView, I should populate it with gson folowing the tutorial from the link?

Comment: you sure you get json data in not null? check him !

Answer (score 0):

I think problem occurs when you make recursive in function `extractFeatureFromJson` when you call `extractFeatureFromJson( webTitle )`, and so on.

Maybe you should share your class `News`, `NewsForDB`, testcases which make exception, and can you tell me the purpose you create an object `newsForDB` without usage?

Comment: I have created NewsForDB.java which will be populated with data from Json.

Comment: The thing what I want to do is to store json locally in database, so app can display news even when there is no Internet connection